# Using CCCallFuncO::create to create a callback to another class

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am writing the following code in a Class

```
CCCallFuncO *cf; 
cf =CCCallFuncO::create(basketLayer, SEL_CallFuncO(SecondClass::addSingleNumberBasket), NULL);
```

The call back is to a another class not containing this code. The compiler is complaining that `invalid use of non-static member function 'void BPBasketLayer::addSingleNumberBasket()`

What am i doing wrong ? How can i create a callback to another class? Can i create the second parameter in the calling class and then use that parameter as a parameter to this function ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make a callback method in the same class. And from this method call the required method with the appropriate parameters. If that method is `non-static` then you could share its instance in the calling class and then use it to call its method